# Which is better to use in Selenium POM, Xpath or FindsBySequence?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am trying to find elements following POM design pattern in Selenium and I would like to know which is a better locator to use? Xpath or FindsBySequence? Planning to use FindsBySequence to find all my inner elements as I read that Xpath takes longer time to identify an element on IE.

ex:

```
[FindsBySequence]    
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "container-dimpanel")]    
[FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "dimselector-row-axis-container")]    
public IList<IWebElement> RowAxisItems { get; set; }


[OR]

[FindsBy(How = How.Xpath, Using = ".//*[@id='container-dimpanel']/div[2]/div[1]/ul")]     
public IList<IWebElement> RowAxisItems { get; set; }
```

Comment: The best one is the one that will take you the less time to debug and understand in 2 weeks if the layout is updated. In your case I would opt for a CSS selector: `#container-dimpanel .dimselector-row-axis-container`.

Comment: Thanks Florent, I will try it with css selector but there are two more nesting after #container-dimpanel. Specifically I am looking to use either Xpath or [FindsBySequence] to edit out much detail for inner elements.